# I FIXED MY OWN: How to replace part of lastname in Active Directory

Tags: replace, trim

So I am trying to determine why the end of a Surname isn't being trimmed or replaced. I've used trim() and replace ("-Disabled, " ") so that I can get only the last name but it seems to not work.
I've looked at various examples yet none seem to be working.

I am using Powershell

```
$results = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Enabled,DisplayName | 
Where-Object{$_.Name -match $regex} | 
Select Name,SurName,DisplayName,Enabled

foreach ($user in $results) {
if ($user.DisplayName -like "*-DISABLED"){
    $SurName = $user.SurName
    $lastName = $SurName.replace("-Disabled"," ")
    write-host $lastname}}
}
```

Prints:

```
 Martin-DISABLED
 Oconnell-DISABLED
 Rodgers-DISABLED
 Hughes-DISABLED
 Anderson-DISABLED
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line of code seem to have taken the last name. It split the **name "-" disabled ** and took back the last name due to using [0]. If I used [-1] then it would have taken Disabled instead.

CODE:

```
$lastName = $SurName.split("-")[0]
```

Comment: can also use [1] and it will return the same thing as [-1]

Answer (score 0):

Your existing code works in my environment, with the exception of the extra "}" after $lastname.

Split worked with this code:

```
$results = Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties Enabled,DisplayName | 
Where-Object{$_.Name -match $regex} | 
Select Name,SurName,DisplayName,Enabled

foreach ($user in $results) 
    {
    if ($user.DisplayName -like "*-DISABLED")
        {
        $SurName = $user.SurName
        $lastName = $SurName.split("-")
        write-host $lastname[0]
        }
}
```

Comment: Thanks I'm not sure if I removed the extra or not but I got my stuff to work. :)